# how to get selected element value by clicking tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on small project. I got some problem when trying to get elements value in the clicked table row. Here is my project codes

```
<table id="info">
    <% for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="prefix<%=i%>" class="form-control">
                <option>044</option>
                <option>51</option>
                <option>555</option>
                <option>43</option>
                <option>33</option>
                <option>66</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="phone" id="number<%=i%>" type="text" onblur="test2()" class="form-control input"  >
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name='status<%=i%>' class="form-control">
                <option>The number is belong to man</option>
                <option>Out of area</option>
                <option>Dialed already</option>
                <option>The number is not defined</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea id="desc<%=i%>" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%}%>
</table>
```

My javascript code is the following:

```
$('#info tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
    var clId = $td.eq(0).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: None of the TD's have an ID ?

Comment: Where is <tbody> tag in your code ?

Comment: `this` will refer to `tr` so `.closest('tr')` is not required here, @lsp modern browser insert it automatically.

Comment: @lsp - It's generally inserted by the browser if you forget it

Comment: I don't understand. You want to get value of `input` field or `select` field?

Comment: Question is not really clear. There is no id in <td>. And most importantly so you need id or value of the element?

Comment: I want to get select field id by clicking tr

Comment: `var id = $(this).find('select').prop('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the selected option value of all `<select>` tags inside all `<td>` tags inside the clicked row, the following script will work

```
$('#info tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).children('td').each(function() {
        $(this).children('select').each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rjvurqdz/2/

If you want to get the value of all elements inside all `<td>` tags inside the clicked row, use this script

```
$('#info tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).children('td').each(function() {
        $(this).children().each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rjvurqdz/6/

Comment: It doesnt give select field id

Comment: See the updated answer, however you'll get undefined alert since the `<select>` tags don't have `id`, did you forget to add the `id`?

Comment: Yes you are right. one question more so how can i get selected option value in this tr using your function?

Comment: You can get it by using `.val()`, see the updated answer and the updated fiddle.

Comment: The last thing i want you to help on it. i want to get all tags value inside td

Comment: Change `.children('select')` to `.children()` to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65760/discussion-between-vaseph-and-ekad).